# X-XSS-Protection header gets set twice - override XssProtection.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, http-header

I use magento 2 (version 2.3) and cloudFlare.

There is an error with  http headers:  X-XSS-Protection header gets set twice because magento add this and then ClouFlare add again.
[See this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230434/console-showing-error-parsing-header-x-xss-protection-1-mode-block-1-mode-bl)

It's not possible to remove CloudFlare headers, so I would like to remove magento XSS header.

I found the solution editing /vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderProvider/XssProtection.php:
I change

```
const HEADER_ENABLED = '1; mode=block';
```

to

```
const HEADER_ENABLED = '0';
```

But I don't want editing the core file. I would like to override it.
Can you explain me how, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify **getValue** method. Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection">
        <plugin name="disable_xssprotection_header"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Framework/App/Response/HeaderProvider/XssProtection.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider;

class XssProtection
{
    public function aroundGetValue(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

***Another solution:***

You can avoid completely this header. In that case, you need to replace the following class.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Framework/App/Response/HeaderProvider/XssProtection.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider;

class XssProtection
{
    public function aroundCanApply(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
       return false;
    }
}
```