# Error Showing in Console "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon" in Magento2

Tags: magento2, http-header

`Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default protections will be applied.`
I am using Apache Server.
How to resolve it.

[image]

A solution below Can anyone explain correctly
[X-XSS-Protection header gets set twice - override XssProtection.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263247/x-xss-protection-header-gets-set-twice-override-xssprotection-php)

Answer (score 1):

Well, The problem is to change the value of the HEADER_ENABLED to 0 because it conflicts with CloudFlare. To achieve this you need to edit this value manually in this core files and this is a very bad way to do this.
So Magento Support overriding Methods by creating a plugin.
Plugin, as Magento defines, is

> A plugin, or interceptor, is a class that modifies the behavior of
>   public class functions by intercepting a function call and running
>   code before, after, or around that function call. This allows you to
>   substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods for any
>   class or interface.

It actually changes the behavior of any method by three types of action

1- **Before**
this one will change the arguments before entering the main method

2- **Around**
this one will change the arguments before entering the main method and also can change the output of this main method

3- **After**
It changes the output of the main method

to define a plugin you need to define it first in your di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection">
        <plugin name="disable_xssprotection_header"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
```

name attribute in type used for the main class you need to add a plugin for
then you need to add a custom name for the plugin and put your class in type attribute and the last attribute is the order of this plugin

After that you will create the plugin class

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider;

class XssProtection
{
    public function aroundGetValue(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

he used the aroundMethod to return 0, However, he would better to use AfterMethod.

You can read more about Plugins from the Magento docs 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**But why he changed this file particularly**
In Magento store-module di.xml You will find this class passed to `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager` as an argument for x-xss-protection

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="headerProviderList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="HSTSHeader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts</item>
                <item name="upgrade-insecure-requests" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\UpgradeInsecure</item>
                <item name="x-content-type-options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XContentTypeOptions</item>
                <item name="x-xss-protection" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

and when we open this class you will find it will add all these arguments to the header of any response in Magento

```
public function beforeSendResponse(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $subject)
    {
        foreach ($this->headerProviders as $provider) {
            if ($provider->canApply()) {
                $subject->setHeader($provider->getName(), $provider->getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

So by overriding method `getValue()` it will return 0 for x-xss-protection, also the other solution of overriding `canApply()` can work because as you see in this code it won't be in the header not just = 0

I hope this helps you